# Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, f#, json.net

I am trying to build a Web Api in F#. I am using .NET 4.5.2, F# 4.0 (FSharp.Core 4.4.0.0). I used the F# templates extension, so this project was created as a WebApi project.

When I launch, I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' 
    or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. 
    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
    Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 
    'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' 
    or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not 
    match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 

Line 23: 
Line 24:     member __.Configuration(builder: IAppBuilder) =
Line 25:         let config = new HttpConfiguration()
Line 26:         Startup.RegisterWebApi(config)
Line 27:         builder.UseWebApi(config) |> ignore
```

I have Newtonsoft.Json on version 10.0.2.

I have tried the following:

- Force-uninstalling & re-installing Newtonsoft.Json
- Adding an assembly binding redirect for Newtonsoft.Json, specifically to version 10.0.2. There was not one there before I added it.
- Newtonsoft.Json is set to copy locally. The dll is in the bin folder of the API, at version 10.0.2

My solution has 3 projects but only the API uses this nuget package.

I know there are a hundred versions of this question on SO, but none of them seem to deal with this error in relation to an F# Api, and I think I have tried all the easy things I've seen listed elsewhere.

Comment: Where did you add the binding redirect?

Comment: I added it to the web.config, in the Assemblies section.

Comment: Well, the error message seems to indicate that the redirect didn't take for some reason. A typo in public key maybe? Try to put garbage in the `web.config` and see if IIS complains about it - this will tell you if `web.config` is getting picked up at all.

Comment: If I add pure garbage to the web config the app refuses to run. When I add a `<system.web>` section next to the one that is already there, I get an IIS 500.19 error, so to me it seems like it is using the web.config.